# php How to include the first line in a file txt

Tags: php

There is a problem when the search does not include the first line. What is the method to include the first line?

```
    $name = trim($_GET['name']);


$file = file('data.txt');

            for($i = 0; $i < count($file); $i++){
            $read = explode('|', $file[$i]);

                    
    if($name == $read[0]){

                            
        $found = 1;
            
                $t1 = $read[0];
                $t2 = $read[1];
```

Comment: Please take the time to properly indent and format your code when asking questions. Please also explain your problem clearly, using sample data and expected output.

Comment: miken32
 The code searches well, but the problem is in the first line

Comment: 1. As miken32 has stated, please post your data.txt file (sample data) too. (Actually I believe your code is ok, it definitely can read the 1st line and do the comparison). 2. At least you should close your if and while block with the closing braces so that it is a complete, minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the following data as sample (data30nov.txt) - I have added a few lines to demonstrate that it can search line 1 and other lines

```
a|125|hh@hh.com 
g|653|uu@uu.com 
vb|603|uu@uu.com
a|1244|hh@hh4444.com 
d|124|hh@hh2.com
```

2. Assuming that you are searching the string "a"
3. Your code should be able to search the 1st line

See the code below

```
<?php
//$name = trim($_GET['name']);
$name = "a";
$file = file('data30nov.txt');

for($i = 0; $i < count($file); $i++){
     $read = explode('|', $file[$i]);

   if ($name == $read[0]){
     $found = 1;
     echo $file[$i]. "<br>";
  }
}
?>
```

The output can be found here:

http://www.createchhk.com/SO/testSO30Nov2021.php

(It shows clearly that the program can search the 1st line)